# Rendering Waypoints

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm writing a code that I can click in the map, parse the info to google maps route for me and save the LatLng in my Data Base. That part, it's ok, it's working. The second part of my page will be render the LatLng that its in my Data Base. Here comes the problem: How do I create an object like google retrieves me when I ask for a route(DirectionsResult Object or DirectionsRoute)? If what I'm trying to do it's wrong, please somebody tell me how to do it right. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please rewrite your question and state what you exactly want. I get lost halfway of your question. Also, use paragraphs to structure your text, this is really not readable.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at google api playground: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#polylines_v3

This example is for printing routes:

```
function initialize() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('theMapCanvas');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180),
    zoom: 2,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var path = [new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
    new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)];

  var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: path,
    strokeColor: '#ff0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  line.setMap(map);
}
```

Comment: I've been looking at Google Examples and didn't find what I need.

Comment: What I really need is create an Object just like the google retrieves me when I request a route (the response object).

Comment: I see. That's an structure that you can create manually, not sure but I don't think there's any other easy way, I would just code it. [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsResult).

Comment: Maybe you should consider a different way to deal with both google response and what you came up from database.

Comment: I'm trying now, to manipulate the object that comes from google servers. By now it's working for redraw the last route I asked. I'll try to save it in my DB and use back in the page.